# ¿Cómo reducir el código de asignación de respuesta?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Alguien tendrá idea de como poder reducir este código, quizás de alguna manera utilizando destructuración, pero no encontré información al respecto.

```
  response.orderQty.currentValue = currentInventory.orderValue
  response.shipmentPrice.currentValue = currentInventory.shipmentPrice
  response.itemsQty = currentInventory.itemsQty
  response.statuses = currentInventory.statuses
  response.countries = currentInventory.countries
```

Comment: Las últimas 2 asignaciones no tienen sentido. Por otro lado, ¿cuál es el problema o error?. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Las preguntas que piden recomendaciones u opiniones terminan cerradas. Saludos

Comment: que es `response.orderQty.currentValue`, pon el código completo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer alguna de las siguientes opciones:

**Opción 1**

```
const { orderValue, shipmentPrice, itemsQty, statuses, countries } = currentInventory;

response.orderQty.currentValue = orderValue;
response.shipmentPrice.currentValue = shipmentPrice;
response.itemsQty = itemsQty;
response.statuses = statuses;
response.countries = countries;
```

**Opción 2:**

```
const { orderValue, shipmentPrice, itemsQty, statuses, countries } = currentInventory;

const newObj = {
  ...response,
  orderQty: { currentValue: orderValue },
  shipmentPrice: { currentValue: shipmentPrice },
  itemsQty,
  statuses,
  countries,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si entiendo del todo bien la pregunta, pero podrías meter todo en un array y usar [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) tal que asi:

```js
[
    response.orderQty.currentValue,
    response.shipmentPrice.currentValue,
    response.itemsQty,
    response.statuses,
    response.countries
] = [
    currentInventory.orderValue,
    currentInventory.shipmentPrice,
    currentInventory.itemsQty,
    currentInventory.statuses,
    currentInventory.countries
];
```

pero esto podria ser contraproducente así que no creo que usaría esta manera de asignación para estos casos.

una mejor opción pero aun no considerada mejor forma seria esta

```js
response = {
  ...response,
  orderQty.currentValue : currentInventory.orderValue,
  shipmentPrice.currentValue : currentInventory.shipmentPrice,
  itemsQty : currentInventory.itemsQty,
  statuses : currentInventory.statuses,
  countries : currentInventory.countries
}
```

Comment: Esto no funciona, no puedes poner como clave orderQty.currentValue